# Border all cell with data, no border all cell without data, using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have data from cell A4:E2000.
What I want to do is to border the range which containing with data (A4:E2000). However, the range cell containing data is random. So I don't want to use fix range in the code.

Further, the rest of the cell without data is set to no border.

How to do this using VBA?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. This is not a free coding service. Show your code and explain where you got errors and which or where you got stuck. You also might read [ask]. This might be helpful: [Range.CurrentRegion Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-currentregion-property-excel) and also the macro recorder might help to figure out some commands.

Comment: If you're ok with a non-VBA solution, 

1) Try selecting the range within which your data resides.
2) Press `F5` and choose `Goto Special` -> `Constants`
3) Apply Borders.

The first step prevents 'Goto Special' from selecting constants from the entire worksheet. So if you do want to select constants from the entire worksheet, skip the first step.

Comment: Is there any data outside `"A4:E2000"`?

Comment: If the suggestion in my previous comment is enough for you, you may consider recording those steps as a macro. But make sure you keep it generalized, i.e., keep the target range selected before you start the macro recorder, to avoid recording navigation. This way you'll record a macro that applies the borders to `Selection`. So, it can be re-usable on any range of cells, regardless of the size.

Comment: Few hints: 1) You can use `ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` to get range of all non-blank cells on an active sheet 2) You can use `Range.Borders` property to draw borders. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simpler conditional formatting to achieve this.You will need three conditional formatting rules. Goto Conditional formatting ==>New Rule==>Use formula.
Enter this formulas separately for each condition.

First rule: `=AND(A3="",A4<>"")` applies to range `=$A$4:$E$2000` . under formatting options choose `Upper` Border.

Second rule: `=AND(A5="",A4<>"")` applies to range `=$A$4:$E$2000`. under formatting options choose `Bottom` Border.

Third rule: `=AND(B4="",A4<>"")`applies to range `=$A$4:$E$2000`. under formatting options choose `Right` Border.

[image]

Result is shown below. If you wish to add left border aswell, use same logic as above.

[image]